# Powerbook G4 1.67 ghz won't sleep on lid close and won't wake from suspend

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, power-management, powerpc

I have a Powerbook G4 running Lubuntu 16.04 (Which I am writing this on, it works quite well), but it won't sleep. When I close it, the Apple logo slowly dims, and then the screen turns off and everything stays on.

When I run `sudo pm-suspend`,
 nothing happens. The program just returns to the terminal.

But when I run `sudo systemctl suspend`, the computer turns off. No fans, no hard drive, no keyboard light.

And when I run `systemctl suspend`, Everything except the keyboard light turns off.

How can I make it sleep? It's the only problem I have with the laptop.

If I had to I could probably make my own sleep driver or something, if I had a reference. I made a fan driver for the laptop before.